# Add user inputs?

Tags: angular, typescript

can you add the user inputs in `Angular`? I am trying to display the result num + 5 in the p tag every time i change the input . Now it displays random values.

`.html` file

```
    <input #box class = "textbox" type="text" name="Name" (change)="keyup(value)>
    <p>{{value}}</p>
```

`.ts` file

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cp1',
  templateUrl: './cp1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cp1.component.css']
})
export class cp1 implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  keyup(num: number) {
    var asd = num + 5;
    this.value = asd;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .ts declare a variable

```
value:any
```

In .html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value">
<p>{{(+value)+5}}</p>
```

But really I think you should take a [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial). I know it spend some time, but give you a general idea of Angular

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you assign `this.value` to `asd` instead of `num` ?

Comment: I forgot to edit this small change here. The result is still not correct

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ngModel` and `ngModelChange`.

Template :

```
<input
  #box
  class="textbox"
  type="text"
  name="Name"
  [(ngModel)]="name"
  (ngModelChange)="addValue()"
/>
<p>{{ name }}</p>
<p>{{ value }}</p>
```

TypeScript :

```
  name: String;
  value = 0;

  addValue() {
    this.value = this.value + 5;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing this.value to keyup in your template.

You want:

```
(change)="keyup(box.value)
```

then in keyup:

```
this.value = num + 5;
```